# How to Set unique IDs to DataRepeater Link Labels

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datarepeater

It is a Windows Form Application in C#.
I am using `DataRepeater` Control in which I am displaying three columns:
`Text Label`,`Link Label`,`Link Label`
Following is the screenshot:
[image]

Following is the code which populates `DataRepeater`:

```
private void Get_StaffLogins_RequestList()
    {
        mySqlConnection = DBAccess.getConnection();
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        DataTable dt = sysadmin.getStaffLoginsRequests(mySqlConnection);
        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

        staff_id.DataBindings.Add("Text", bSource, "staff_id");
        //accessLink.DataBindings.Add("Value", bSource, "staff_id");
        //denyLink.DataBindings.Add("Value", bSource, "staff_id");

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            bSource.DataSource = dt;
            r_msgs.DataSource = bSource;
        }
        else
        {
            r_msgs.DataSource = String.Empty;
            notify.Text = "There are no Pending requests for staff logins!";
        }
        mySqlConnection.Close();
    }

    private void accessLink_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Access Link Clicked
    }

    private void denyLink_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Deny Link Clicked
    }
```

Now what I need is that when User clicks on `Access` or `Deny` Link I somehow get corresponding StaffID so that I can mark that particular staffID Access/Denied in Database.

**How can I attribute each Row Link Labels with unique staff ids?** 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by getting Current Item Index of DataRepeater:

```
private void accessLink_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Access Link Clicked
        int RequestNumber = r_msgs.CurrentItemIndex;
        MessageBox.Show(RequestNumber.toString()+1);
        //Remaining Code
    }
```

This code Prints the Row number of the Access Link Label, and that's what I wanted!